# chrome extension browser action pop up never redirects to external url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**manifest.js**

```
     {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "My Test Extension",
      "description": "This extension demonstrates.",
      "version": "1.0",

      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon" :"GB-19.png"

      },
     "icons": {
          "128": "GB-128.png",
          "16": "GB-19.png",
          "48": "GB-48.png"
       },
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },
      "permissions": [
          "tabs",
           "activeTab",
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
      ]
    }
```

**background.js**

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab){ 
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({"tabId": tab.Id,"popup":"Login.html"});
    });
```

> Instead of Login.html if I try to hit any other url (my app hosted
>   url)
>
> for  example https://www.facebook.com/ pop up shows file not found.
>   Note : I want to open my hosted app through chrome extension pop up only ( tab one works fine at my end)

Comment: The question doesn't contain all relevant code so it's not clear what is the problem. Also, I'm not sure the popup supports redirection to an external URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for yur comment here .                                            I have a manifest.js background.js and a login.html with hello as text . Now if I redirect to Login.html it works fine (pop up renders html text "hello") but if I redirect to any external url like https://www.facebook.com/ the pop up shows file not found . I tried lot many options but of no use. If anybody can help me with any thing it wud be great.